# How to fetch nested values in MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a 3 layer nested document something like this.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b5acaf0589ff6bfb5dd091f"),
"date" : "2018/07/31",
"clock" : [ 
    {
        "time" : "10:12:02",
        "values" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "A1003",
                "value" : "777"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "A0001",
                "value" : "888"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "time" : "13:12:02",
        "values" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "A1003",
                "value" : "111"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I'm able to sort the date by using `$gte` `$lte` as below and all values are fetched.

```
getData(name: string[], fromDate: string, toDate: string): Promise<{ message: string }> {
    return this._mongoUtility.testDb
        .then(db => {
            let collection = db.collection('TestDoc');
            let fromOnlyDate = fromDate.split(' ');
            let toOnlyDate = toDate.split(' ');
            return collection.find({
                'date': {
                    $gte: `${fromOnlyDate[0]}`,
                    $lte: `${toOnlyDate[1]}`
                }
            }).toArray();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return Promise.reject({message: 'Data not found', err: err})
        })
}
```

I want to filter by using `time` and again by `name` and should display the `value`.

I tried in many ways but I'm getting the result. Is there nay other method to do so in MongoDB? Kindly suggest.

Expected output should look like below

```
0:{date: "2018/07/31 10:12:02", value-A1003: "777", value-A0001: "888"}
1:{date: "2018/07/31 13:12:02", value-A1003: "111"}
```

Comment: its hard to understand what you want your output will be can you add desired output please

Comment: @AmitWagner I have edited the above post.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the aggregate framwork to achive a simmler result(you cant create attr by value)

```js
db.getCollection('sss').aggregate([

    {$unwind:'$clock'},
    {$unwind:'$clock.values'},
    {$project:{
         date: {$concat:[  "$date" ,' ' ,  "$clock.time" ]},
         value:'$clock.values.value',
         name:'$clock.values.name'
     }}

])
```